# Android radio button-display something based on radioButton gives onClick error

Tags: android, onclick, radio-button

I'm new to android programming and building my first app.It is supposed to display a message about two numbers, based on what is selected in a RadioGroup.My problem is that i keep getting errors when clicking the "find out" button, which are related to onClick.

```
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radio, int checkedId) {
    count = checkedId;
}
public void executa(View v){
       RadioButton radioButton1=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
       RadioButton radioButton2=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
       RadioButton radioButton3=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);
       RadioButton radioButton4=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton4);
       Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button); 
     RadioGroup radio=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio);
    if (v.getId() == R.id.button){
    count = radio.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Text1);
       int nr1=Integer.getInteger(editText1.getText().toString());  
       EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Text2);
       int nr2=Integer.getInteger(editText2.getText().toString());  

       pozitive=0;

       negative=0;

       if (nr1==nr2) max=min=-1; else
       if (nr1>nr2){  max=nr1;
                                   min=nr2;}
       else {  max=nr2;
           min=nr1;}
      if (nr1>0) pozitive++;
                else negative--;
      if (nr2>0) pozitive++;
        else negative--;

    Intent intent=new Intent(this,Raspuns.class);
    switch(count){
    case 1:intent.putExtra(Valoare, max);
    break;
    case 2:intent.putExtra(Valoare, min);
    break;
    case 3:intent.putExtra(Valoare, pozitive);
    break;
    case 4:intent.putExtra(Valoare, negative);
    break;
    }
    startActivity(intent);  
}
}
 @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


 }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
            return false;
        }

}
```

Also,the message is sent via an intent to a second activity,called from executa,by clicking the afla button.Thanks for any advice!
EDIT:logcat:

```
12-02 00:12:11.788: E/AndroidRuntime(3524): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-02 00:12:11.788: E/AndroidRuntime(3524): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
12-02 00:12:11.788: E/AndroidRuntime(3524):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3044)
12-02 00:12:11.788: E/AndroidRuntime(3524):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
12-02 00:12:11.788: E/AndroidRuntime(3524):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14109)
12-02 00:12:11.788: E/AndroidRuntime(3524):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-02 00:12:11.788: E/AndroidRuntime(3524):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-02 00:12:11.788: E/AndroidRuntime(3524):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-02 00:12:11.788: E/AndroidRuntime(3524):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
12-02 00:12:11.788: E/AndroidRuntime(3524):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-02 00:12:11.788: E/AndroidRuntime(3524):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-02 00:12:11.788: E/AndroidRuntime(3524):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-02 00:12:11.788: E/AndroidRuntime(3524):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-02 00:12:11.788: E/AndroidRuntime(3524):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-02 00:12:11.788: E/AndroidRuntime(3524): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-02 00:12:11.788: E/AndroidRuntime(3524):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-02 00:12:11.788: E/AndroidRuntime(3524):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-02 00:12:11.788: E/AndroidRuntime(3524):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
12-02 00:12:11.788: E/AndroidRuntime(3524):     ... 11 more
12-02 00:12:11.788: E/AndroidRuntime(3524): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-02 00:12:11.788: E/AndroidRuntime(3524):     at com.example.myfirstrealandroidapp.MainActivity.executa(MainActivity.java:48)
12-02 00:12:11.788: E/AndroidRuntime(3524):     ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input! It seems the error of my app was that i used `"Integer.getInt`" instead of "`Integer.parseInt"`. Also,it gave the correct answer when i used the radio listener and button

Answer (score 0):

```
   RadioButton radioButton1=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);

   RadioButton radioButton2=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);

   RadioButton radioButton3=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);
   RadioButton radioButton4=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton4);
   Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button); 
   RadioGroup radio=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio);
    radio.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        count = checkedId;
    }
});
```